# Adding extra variables to summarize_at in the R dplyr package

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I am using R's `dplyr` package to obtain summary statistics for several variables, many of which are all similarly named.  For example, I have several hundred variables that are all named `doctor_id_X`, where `X` is some integer (e.g. `doctor_id_1`, `doctor_id_33`, `doctor_id_543`, etc.).  I am able to easily obtain the maximum value of these "`doctor_id`" variables, grouped by `treatment1`, using so-called "helpers" inside a `summarize_at` statement like this:

```
mydf %>% group_by(treatment1) %>% 
summarize_at(vars(contains("doctor_id")), max)
```

However, in addition to obtaining these `max` statistics, I'm trying to obtain the mean of some other variable that is not named similar to one of the  `doctor_id` variables, call it `procedure_time`.  Is there a way for me to do this efficiently by modifying my code above?

To better explain, what I'm trying to do, here's a toy example of a dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(20190813)
mydf <- data.frame(treatment1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
                   treatment2 = sample(LETTERS[4:5], 100, replace=TRUE), 
                   doctor_id_1=rbinom(100, 1, .01),
                   doctor_id_2=rbinom(100, 1, .5),
                   doctor_id_3=rbinom(100, 1, .6),
                   doctor_id_4=rbinom(100, 1, .7),
                   y=rnorm(100))
    head(mydf)

  treatment1 treatment2 doctor_id_1 doctor_id_2 doctor_id_3 doctor_id_4          y
1          A          D           0           0           1           0 -1.1175362
2          A          E           0           0           1           1 -2.2813598
3          A          D           0           1           1           0  0.5886914
4          A          D           0           0           1           1  0.9854405
5          B          E           0           0           1           1  1.8831306
6          A          E           0           1           1           1 -0.3875261
```

It's no problem getting the `max` value summaries by the `doctor_id` variables with this:

```
mydf %>% group_by(treatment1) %>% 
   summarize_at(vars(contains("doctor_id")), max)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  treatment1 doctor_id_1 doctor_id_2 doctor_id_3 doctor_id_4
  <fct>            <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>
1 A                    1           1           1           1
2 B                    0           1           1           1
3 C                    0           1           1           1
```

But now, I want to also find the `mean` of `y` in my summarize statement.  I tried this but it did not work:

```
mydf %>% group_by(treatment1) %>% 
   summarize_at(y_avg=mean(y), vars(y, contains("doctor_id")), max)
```

I did note, however, that the following gets me a little closer to what I want, only it's producing the `max` for all the `doctor_id` variable and the `y` variable, but I need just the `mean` for the `y` variable.

```
mydf %>% group_by(treatment1) %>% 
summarize_at(vars(y, contains("doctor_id")), max)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  treatment1     y doctor_id_1 doctor_id_2 doctor_id_3 doctor_id_4
  <fct>      <dbl>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>
1 A           1.70           1           1           1           1
2 B           1.88           0           1           1           1
3 C           1.45           0           1           1           1
```

This also gets me close, but it produces both statistics for both variables:

```
mydf %>% group_by(treatment1) %>% 
   summarize_at(vars(y, contains("doctor_id")), c(max, mean))
```

**So, to summarize, my question is, is there any way to use the helper function in a summarize_by statement and also include a different statistic for another variable, without having to resort to joins?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option where we create a variable 'y_avg' either with `mutate` (and then add that also in the `group_by`) or directly in `group_by` after the 'treatment' grouped data, then do the `summarise_at`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
   group_by(treatment1)  %>%
   group_by(y_avg = mean(y), add = TRUE ) %>% 
   summarize_at(vars(contains("doctor_id")), max)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups:   treatment1 [3]
#  treatment1    y_avg doctor_id_1 doctor_id_2 doctor_id_3 doctor_id_4
#  <fct>         <dbl>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>
#1 A          -0.216             0           1           1           1
#2 B           0.0659            0           1           1           1
#3 C          -0.00830           1           1           1           1
```

---

or another option is to create the the 'y_avg' in `mutate` and then use it in `group_by`

```
mydf %>%
   group_by(treatment1) %>%
   mutate(y_avg = mean(y) %>%
   group_by(y_avg, add = TRUE) %>%
   summarize_at(vars(contains("doctor_id")), max)
```

---

Or another option is to `select` only the variable of interest, after grouping by 'treatment' use `mutate` and `mutate_at` to update the columns, then the `distinct` rows of the dataset

```
mydf %>%
   select(treatment1, y_avg = y, contains('doctor_id')) %>% 
   group_by(treatment1) %>% 
   mutate(y_avg = mean(y_avg)) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(contains('doctor_id')), max) %>%
   distinct
```

---

Or an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, c(.(y_avg = mean(y)), lapply(.SD, max)),
        .(treatment1), .SDcols = grep('doctor_id', names(mydf))]
#.  treatment1        y_avg doctor_id_1 doctor_id_2 doctor_id_3 doctor_id_4
#1:          C -0.008299684           1           1           1           1
#2:          B  0.065875911           0           1           1           1
#3:          A -0.216200359           0           1           1           1
```

Comment: This is great!  Thank you sooo much.  I'm not sure I understand why this can be done, but it does work.  I'm going to leave this open to see if there are some other possible solutions.  If I don't see a better solution after a few hours, I'll accept.  Thanks again!

Comment: @StatsStudent. With `dplyr`, partially applying different functions to different columns in `mutate_all/at/if` is not currenlty implemented.  But, it can be done in `data.table` though

Answer (score 1):

We can `group_by` `treatment` calculate `mean` of `y` using `mutate`, add that column in `summarise_at` to get `max` of all columns.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>% 
  group_by(treatment1) %>% 
  mutate(y_avg = mean(y)) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(y_avg, contains("doctor_id")), max)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  treatment1   y_avg doctor_id_1 doctor_id_2 doctor_id_3 doctor_id_4
#  <fct>        <dbl>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>
#1 A          -0.192            1           1           1           1
#2 B          -0.0390           0           1           1           1
#3 C          -0.165            0           1           1           1
```